# sql call from two table

Tags: php, sql

I trying to create a loop with data from 2 tables, this thing is giving me an error that says, results more than one row. Here's the script.

```
$query_amoline = "SELECT * FROM `penny_players` WHERE `memid`=\"$curmemid\" AND id=   (SELECT   id FROM `penny` WHERE `active`='Y') ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$amoline = mysql_query($query_amoline) or die(mysql_error());
$row_amoline = mysql_fetch_assoc($amoline);
$totalRows_amoline = mysql_num_rows($amoline);

<? if($totalRows_amoline>0)
{ ?> 
<?php do { ?>
<?php
$id=$row_amoline['id'];
$pid=$row_amoline['pennyid'];

if($totalRows_amoline>0)
{ ?> 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if

```
SELECT   id FROM `penny` WHERE `active`='Y'
```

returns more then one id, your query will fail.

Change to:

```
"SELECT * FROM `penny_players` WHERE `memid`=\"$curmemid\" AND id IN (SELECT   id FROM `penny` WHERE `active`='Y') ORDER BY `id` DESC";
```

Comment: You guys are freaking geniusses

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `... AND id IN (...`, since more than one row in `penny` has `active` set to `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT pp.* 
    FROM penny_players pp
    WHERE pp.memid=\"$curmemid\"
        AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                       FROM penny p
                       WHERE p.id = pp.id 
                           AND p.active = 'Y') 
    ORDER BY pp.id DESC"
```